# Company video streaming to customers

Tags: video, audio, streaming

our company need from time to time make some video conferences.

Microsoft Lync and Skype solutions are not good because we need to stream up to 2000 viewers.

My idea is to use some service like http://www.justin.tv/ and http://www.xsplit.com/ to broadcast.

But we have some requirements:

1. wee need to embedded stream to our intranet website
2. password protected streams (or just not public stream)
3. stream archive - download video

Thanks for help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adobe Connect may do what you are looking for.  It has a couple of different pricing tiers, one for upto 100 people, and then a much more expensive, much larger style license.

Embedding im not sure about.

Password protecting is doable, people would need to be invited/approved before they could join.

Stream archive - absolutely.  You can record the entire stream inside of Connect itself, then make any timing edits to it that you need, and provide users, or a website archive with the url to view the meeting at any time.

Comment: It looks really nice. Any other and cheaper solutions using Xsplit? ;)

Comment: But it looks really great... ;)

Comment: @MarekJavůrek;  Glad to know it looks positive.

Answer (score 0):

I believe [LiveStream](http://new.livestream.com/broadcast-live/livestream-your-events) should able to meet all your needs.

Comment: Its interesting too. THX. But Adobe Connect is our winner ;)